# Regex match is null

Tags: c#, regex

I have:

```
string cap = "OK|pz6u1";
var id = Regex.Match(cap, @"OK\|(.*?)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Why id is null?­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: If the string is always in the format `<something>|<id>` then a regex is a bit over kill, a simple split would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to below one:

```
var id = Regex.Match(cap, @"OK\|(.*)").Groups[1].Value
```

The problem in your expression was a question mark (?). Question mark mark makes the **previous** statement **optional**, so that is way it was omitted.

Comment: Mark response as answer instead of writing comments

Comment: @Garath this answer could be improved by an explanation

Comment: The `?` in `.*?` does not mean optional. The `*?` denotes a non-greedy match. So `.*?` denotes a non-greedy match. When there is nothing after the non-greedy match apart from `)` means an empty string matches.